# How to get last 7 day's data from current datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    VEEMS_CREATED_DATE
FROM 
    VEEMS_SHIP_STATE_DATA 
WHERE 
    VEEMS_CREATED_DATE <= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
ORDER BY 
    VEEMS_CREATED_DATE
```

Comment: Use >= in WHERE statement

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract directly from `getdate()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT VEEMS_CREATED_DATE 
FROM VEEMS_SHIP_STATE_DATA 
WHERE VEEMS_CREATED_DATE <=  **GETDATE() - 7**
ORDER BY VEEMS_CREATED_DATE
```

Comment: i think you mean >=.

Comment: Hi Sonam mam, I tried your code but it brings all the records in that table.It didn't bring me 7 days records from current date.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `DATEDIFF`

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day,VEEMS_CREATED_DATE,GETDATE()) between 0 and 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Datetime BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```